# Navigation in Django, using url.patterns

Tags: python, django

I learn Python, doing test project.

Case: I need to use `class="active"` for `<li>` based on page url. Now I use `django.core.context_processors.request` to take url from `path`.

How it looks now:

```
<li role="presentation" {% if request.path == '/' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation" {% if '/groups' in request.path %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'groups' %}">Groups</a></li>
```

So, if I open main page - first `<li>` is active, if url contains `"/groups"` - secon `<li>` is active. And it works, but I want to do it more complex, comparing url with `url.patterns` in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', 'students.views.students_list', name='home'),
url(r'^groups/$', 'students.views.groups_list', name='groups')
```

**Question:** how to do it? I can't just use `{% url 'groups' %}` in `if`-statement because of syntax error. Need some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result of url tag to the variable.

```
{% url 'groups' as groups_url %}

# use groups_url variable somewhere
```

Comment: GREAT Answer, thanks very much, but I can't mark it as an answer, why?